# Formatting predefined types in code eclipse oxygen [c++]

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt, code-formatting, user-defined-types

If the type is defined with `#define` eclipse is removing the space between type and variable name. It's okay with typedef.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef vector<int> vi;
#define vs vector<string>

int main() {
    vi v1; // no problem
    vs v2; // after pressing ctrl+shift+f, space between vs and v2 is sucked up..
   //producing some syntax errors

    return 0;
}
```

> Version info:

```
Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers
Version: Oxygen.3 Release (4.7.3)
Build id: 20180308-1800
OS: Windows 10, v.10.0, x86_64 / win32
```

Any way to fix this, thanks.

Comment: I know this won't help but with `typedef` and `using` there is no reason to use `#define` to alias a type.

Comment: `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` - don't do that, it's not clever, and it's not portable.

Comment: @NeilButterworth it's for contests only :)

Comment: `using vs = vector<string>;`. Problem solved.

Comment: As I said it's not clever, because it means that some of the people you are asking advice from will not be able to compile your code. And as you are obviously still learning C++, so-called "contests" are a bad way to go.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug in Eclipse CDT's code formatter. I filed [this bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=533033) for it (but be aware that CDT's formatter hasn't seen much maintenance in recent years, so it's not likely to be fixed soon).

As already mentioned, a simple workaround is to replace the `#define` with a `typedef`.

You could also use an Eclipse plugin that provides a better formatter than the built-in one, such as [this plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/cppstyle) which uses clang-format.